# Javascript html find all elements visually under or over (intersecting with) a specific element

Tags: javascript, html, z-index

Is there a way to find all the other html elements that a specific element is over/under or intersecting with?

I want to make sure that element is shown above all of the others so I want to find all the intersecting elements and set the element's `z-index` to a value more than all of the other elements' `z-index`s.

Comment: Not sure there is any way to do this programmatically. If you just mean you want to check a particular situation on one page you are working on, bring it up in a browser like Firefox or Chrome, right click over the html element you are interested in, choose inspect or inspect element, go look at the inspector, and move around in the inspector to see what is in the way. There may well be a better or faster way. This is the way I generally do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution assuming that the element has `z-index` set on their `style` attribute and not computer from the css: (code is in typescript)

```
export function getMaxZIndexOfOverlappingElements(target: HTMLElement): number {
    const zIndexElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("*[style*=z-index]"))
    let zIndex = 0
    zIndexElements.forEach(el => {
        if (el instanceof HTMLElement && overlap(target, el)) {
            try {
                zIndex = Math.max(zIndex, parseInt(firstNotEmpty(el.style.zIndex, "0")))
            } catch (e) {
                // skip invalid zIndex value
            }
        }
    })
    return zIndex
}
```